# How to convert dtype '<U28' to a sparse matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working on a project which predicts the cuisine on the basis of food ingredients entered. But the input is a string and predict() requires a sparse matrix. 
I have tried sparse.csr_matrix() and sparse.coo_matrix() but both didn't work and is generating an error **"Type Error:No supported conversion for types: (dtype('U28'),)"**

```
s = df_ingredients.all_ingredients.values[0] //df_ingredients is the 
                                  //dataframe of the training dataset, 
                                  //all_ingredients is a column of 
                                  //df_ingredients having all the 
                                  //ingredients in a particular cuisine

n_array = np.array(s.split(';'))
s_matrix = sparse.csr_matrix(n_array) //This generates the Type Error
logistic.predict(s_matrix)            //s_matrix is required here
```

Comment: You should paste your data schema and code

Comment: What it says, you can't make scipy sparse matrux with string elements.

Comment: Does 'predict' work with strings? or some numeric encoding (one integer for each unique word)? What predict is this?